# ObjC properties and C operators

Tags: objective-c, properties, operators, increment, compound-assignment

Given the following property declaration:

```
@property NSInteger foo;
```

How do the increment, decrement, and compound assignment operators actually work on `self.foo`?

It was my understanding that `self.foo` was merely syntactic sugar for the actual accessor methods.  So `self.foo` isn't directly accessing an `NSInteger` variable called `foo`, but rather calling either:

```
- (void)setFoo:(NSInteger)foo;
```

or

```
- (NSInteger)foo;
```

Yet, the following set of code is perfectly fine, is not flagged, compiles fine, and returns exactly the expected results:

```
self.foo = 0;
NSLog(@"%d",self.foo); // prints 0

self.foo += 1;
NSLog(@"%d",self.foo); // prints 1

self.foo++;
NSLog(@"%d",self.foo); // prints 2

++self.foo;
NSLog(@"%d",self.foo); // prints 3
```

And I think it's probably safe to assume that the decrement pre and post fix operators as well as the other 9 compound operators will do exactly what you'd expect if you were using them directly on an `NSInteger` variable.

I just don't understand WHY it works if `self.foo` is truly just syntactic sugar for the two methods I mentioned above.

If I overwrite the default accessors to include `NSLog` statements so I can see when each is called and with what values, I can see that the getter is called first then the setter is called.

Does this mean that the following:

```
self.foo += 1;
```

is effectively replaced with this:

```
[self setFoo:([self foo] + 1)];
```

during precompilation?

---

**EDIT:** So, at the assembly level, is there any difference between `self.foo += 1;` and `self.foo = self.foo + 1;`?  What if we're not talking about a property, and `bar` is just a regular int, at the assembly level is there a difference between `bar += 1;` and `bar = bar + 1;`?

Comment: Exactly. Your assumption is correct.

Comment: Given the results, it seems clear that your assumption is correct.

Comment: I've added an addendum to my question to try clarifying what I'm actually getting at.

Comment: @nhgrif I have added an answer of your question to my post. Please check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly. Your assumption is correct. You can implement property yourself and add logging to  check your assumption one more time

In your @interface section:

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger foo; 
     // nonatomic keyword is not really required but 
     // it is better to add it since we will implement 
     // property as nonatomic
```

In @implementation section:

```
- (void)setFoo:(NSInteger)foo
{
    _foo = foo; // _foo variable is implicitly generated by compiler
    NSLog(@"set foo %d", _foo);
}

- (NSInteger)foo
{
    NSLog(@"get foo %d", _foo);
    return _foo;
}
```

Then run

```
self.foo = 0;
self.foo += 1;
```

you should receive in debug window:

```
set foo 0
get foo 0
set foo 1
```

UPDATE:

- Re: "at the assembly level, is there any difference between `self.foo += 1;` and `self.foo = self.foo + 1;`?"

No.  For both `[self setFoo:([self foo] + 1)];` will be called.

- Re: What if we're not talking about a property, and bar is just a regular int, at the assembly level is there a difference between `bar += 1;` and `bar = bar + 1;`?

Yes. But only if compile time optimization is turned off.

`bar += 1;` is faster. It will be compiled to something like:

```
mov eax,dword ptr [bar]
inc eax                // difference is here!
mov dword ptr [bar],eax
```

And `bar = bar + 1;` to:

```
mov eax,dword ptr [bar]
add eax,1              // difference is here!
mov dword ptr [bar],eax
```

Comment: So compound operators are a little misleading on Objective-C properties if you're expecting them to behave like they do in other languages.  Can I assume the same assembly difference for non-properties with increment/decrement operators?

Comment: @nhgrif not sure I understand you correctly. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: `self.someVar++`, `someVar++`, `++self.someVar`, `++someVar`, and minus as well.

Comment: @nhgrif yes, they all have the same behaviour.